# Preload may have stalled wp supercache

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins

I have received many emails from my wordpress blog with subject: 
`preload may have stalled`

and in the text i receive:

```
Preload has been restarted.

http://example.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wpsupercache“
```

I searched too much but didn't get any solution ..

Is it a notice when the cache is flushed?

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, but I talked with the Support of my hosting.

There is no problem, so do not worry about this Message, because Support stuff told me that.

[TheAnswer] The cause of this problem is in changing or modifying one of settings on server[by hosting Company], during the resolving one of problems, your Website may stall, and this Plugin[Wp-super-cache] will notify you about this stalling and preloading his files from backup.

This is Everything :) .

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying email, and still they have not updated the solution despite peoples complaints. I too received a **Preloader may have stalled** email daily.

I found a temp solution though. Open the wp-cache.php file from within the wp-super-cache folder (**your-doman**/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php).

Within the file search for "**Preload may have stalled**" It should be in a section of code like the below:

```
wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), sprintf( __( '[%s] Preload may have stalled.', 'wp-super-cache' ), get_bloginfo( 'url' ) ), sprintf( __( "Preload has been restarted.\n%s", 'wp-super-cache' ), admin_url( "options-general.php?page=wpsupercache" ) ) );
```

Now, change where it says **admin_email** to **NeverEmailMeAgain@Please.com** and you are good to go!

So it should look something like this:

```
wp_mail( get_option( 'NeverEmailMeAgain@Please.com' ), sprintf( __( '[%s] Preload may have stalled.', 'wp-super-cache' ), get_bloginfo( 'url' ) ), sprintf( __( "Preload has been restarted.\n%s", 'wp-super-cache' ), admin_url( "options-general.php?page=wpsupercache" ) ) );
```

And your done! :)

(NOTE: As mentioned this is a temp fix. Once you update the plugin you will have to update the email address again unfortunately - But it works for now)

Comment: This does not look like a fix or explanation, but only stops the email from being sent.

Comment: It is a “temp fix” as I previously mentioned. This was over 5 years ago, so it wouldn’t surprise me if it had been patched by now.